# How can I embed a MovieClip from a SWF into a Flex app without looping it?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, movieclip

I'm stumped on this one, but it seems like something simple I'm overlooking.

My Flex app embeds (i.e., compiles in) another SWF's MovieClip, like so:

```
[Embed(source='assets/clips.swf', symbol='MyClip')] 
private var MyClip:Class;
```

... and then uses an `mx:Image` tag to display it:

```
<mx:Image source="{MyClip}" width="300" height="100" />
```

... but the resulting clip loops forever.  I want it to play only once and then stop.

The source clip has a `stop()` action defined in its final frame, but I suspect that script is being stripped out at compile time, so I'm wondering how I can tell the Image tag, or MyClip class somehow, that the clip should not loop continuously.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I do not work with Flex, so these ideas are not something I know by practice; but here is what I have found:

> If the SWF file contains any ActionScript code, Flex prints a warning
>   during compilation and then strips out the ActionScript from the embed
>   symbol. This means that you can only embed the symbol itself. -- http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=embed_4.html

Also, I believe `MyClip` is a `Class`, and not an instance of that class on the stage.  So . . . you have to do something like:

```
<mx:Image source="{new MyClip()}" width="300" height="100" />
```

or create a variable and work with it, like [this example from Adobe docs](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=controls_16.html).

If all this ends up being in the realm of truth, then you can play() and stop() as any other embedded SWF.